# Auto exit Access on idle

Tags: vba, ms-access

In access using VB my code is:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

Static OldcontrolName As String
Static OldFormName As String
Static ExpiredTime

Dim ActivecontrolName As String
Dim ActiveFormName As String
Dim ExpiredMinutes

On Error Resume Next

ActivecontrolName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name
ActiveFormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name

If (OldcontrolName = "") Or (OldFormName = "") Or (ActiveFormName <> OldFormName) Or 
(ActivecontrolName <> OldcontrolName) Then
    OldcontrolName = ActivecontrolName
    OldFormName = ActiveFormName
    ExpiredTime = 0
Else

    ExpiredTime = ExpiredTime + Me.TimerInterval

End If

ExpiredMinutes = (ExpiredTime / 1000)

If ExpiredMinutes >= 600 Then
    ExpiredTime = 0
    Application.Quit acQuitSaveAll
    
End If

End Sub
```

This seems to work great. I can put the time down to 5 seconds to test and it's perfect but as soon as I turn off the navigation pane and then try to close access it throws the error:

```
Run-time error '5':

Invalid procedure call or argument
```

Comment: Eh... You've got an `On Error Resume Next` in front of all your code, so the code you've shared is not visibly causing that error.

Comment: the error only appears when you go to options and go to current database and uncheck display navigation pane, it will then say you have to close and reopen the database for it to take effect, so close and reopen the database, now the navigation pane will be hidden and when you click close you will not get the run time error

Comment: That may be true but it doesn't mean that the code you posted has any relation to the error you see. To prove it, comment out this code and see if the problem goes away. If it doesn't then your princess is in another castle.